# Codeigniter Extracting Information, Function Isn't Working

Tags: database, codeigniter, function

I'm attempting to extract information from my mysql database. I believe I'm properly joining tables (function syntax below) but when I try and display the extracted information inside of a view, nothing is showing up. I used var_dump and my array is saying

> array (size=0) empty

I'm also getting these error messages as well.

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: views/view_show_all_averages.php
>
> Line Number: 6
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined offset: 0
>
> Filename: views/view_show_all_averages.php
>
> Line Number: 7

My question is, where do you think I'm going wrong. What are some steps I should take to go about fixing my issue? (syntax below) Thanks Everyone.

My Model_data function

```
function getJoinInformation($year,$make,$model)
{
 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('tbl_car_description d');
 $this->db->join('tbl_car_prices p', 'd.id = p.cardescription_id');
 $this->db->where('d.year', $year);
 $this->db->where('d.make', $make);
 $this->db->where('d.model', $model);
 $query = $this->db->get();
 return $query->result();
}
```

My Site Controller

```
   public function getAllInformation($year,$make,$model)
   {
     if(is_null($year)) return false;
     if(is_null($make)) return false;
     if(is_null($model)) return false;
     $this->load->model('model_data');
     $data['allvehicledata'] = $this->model_data->getJoinInformation($year,$make,$model);
     $this->load->view('view_show_all_averages',$data);
   }
```

My View

```
<?php
var_dump($allvehicledata);

if(isset($allvehicledata) && !is_null($allvehicledata))
{  

    echo $allvehicledata->make. ' ' .$allvehicledata->model . "<br />";
    $make = $allvehicledata[0]->make;
    echo "$make";
    // $state = $cities[0]->state;
    // echo '<hr>';

    foreach ($allvehicledata as $car)
    {
      echo anchor('site/getAllInformation/'.$car->year.'/'.$car->make.'/'.$car->model, $car->year.' '.$car->make.' '.$car->model, array('title'=>$car->make.' '.$car->model)).'<br>';
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your notice errors are happening because you are returning an array from your model function, yet are calling the data like it is an object. If you only want to retrieve one row of data from the DB, use `row()` instead of `result()`. Read [Generating Query Results](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) for more info.

The query you're running is not failing, but it is not returning any results. Chances are your WHERE conditions are not being given the values that you assume they are (that's my guess, anyway).

Use `echo $this->db->last_query()` after you perform the DB query to see exactly what SQL is being sent, and use that to figure out what may be wrong and why the result set is empty.

Comment: Yes it does. `return $query->result();` result() is *always* an array.